# how to make subview shadow bleeding out from parent view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, hstack

As the title explained, I need make the shadow of subview bleeding out from parent bounds.

We can see the shadow is clipped by the container (parent view). How to ignore it?

[image]

```swift
ScrollView(axis, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack{

        ForEach(d_keys.indices) { index -> DownloadOptionView in

            let d_key = d_keys[index]
            let d_info = asset.downloads[d_key]!
            
            return DownloadOptionView(d_key: d_key, d_info: d_info)
        }.padding(.vertical, 10) // ForEach
    }
}.frame(minHeight:130)
```

// View structure for DownloadOptionView, modified, may not compile

```
struct DownloadOptionView: View {
    let d_key: String
    let d_info: DownloadInfo

    // some @ObservedObject ...........
    // some @State ...........
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return NavigationLink(destination: SceneKitCanvas(textureMap: textureMap), isActive: self.$present) {
            
        Button(action: {
            
            // Download / storage / animation      
        }) {
            ZStack{
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Neumorphism.background, Neumorphism.light]),
                               startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                
                Color.green.scaleEffect(x: 1.0, y: CGFloat(scale), anchor: .bottom) // progress bar
                Color.green.scaleEffect(x: 1.0, y: CGFloat(increased), anchor: lineAnchor)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Image(systemName: imageName).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        Text(file_type).fontWeight(.light)
                    }.padding(.bottom, 5)
                    Text(d_key).font(.footnote).fontWeight(.light)
                    Text(size_final).font(.footnote).fontWeight(.light)
                    
                }.padding() // VStack
            } // ZStack
        }
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
        .shadow(color: Color.white, radius: 3, x: -3, y: -3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `DownloadOptionView`?

Comment: Thanks, it's quite long code. Basically, some ZStack VStack inside Button, then Button is wrapped in NavigationLink. Shadow is applied on Button.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some guesswork about how you created `DownloadOptionView` but the answer can be used in your context as it's a general technique.

Where you are creating `DownloadOptionView` you need to add the `.blendMode(.overlay)` modifier:

```
struct DownloadOptionView: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous).path(in: rect)
    }

    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
        .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
        .blendMode(.overlay) //Add here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I applied the `.blendMode(.overlay)` at several different place, `Button` `HStack` `ScrollView` But it seems not working.

Comment: It needs to be on the view which has the shadow modifier.

Comment: Not on any other views.

Comment: I tried it before and after `.shadow(*******)`, didn't work.

Comment: can you share your `DownloadOptionView` code? i’m not sure what is the issue as it works in my case and should work for simple view layouts.

Comment: Hey, I posted it in the description.

Comment: any solution ever come of this? having the same issue.